# error when run hprof-conv.exe

Tags: android, memoryanalyzer

I got error `ERROR: read 46402 of 4259932 bytes` when run `hprof-conv.exe` and the file it created could not be opened with MemoryAnalyzer.exe with error `Illegal record length 0 at byte 5,408,931 for record type 1`.

I used `android.os.Debug.dumpHprofData("/data/misc/dump.hprof");` to created the dump file and used `C:\>adb pull /data/misc/dump.hprof` to get the dump file from emulator.

Does anyone know what's wrong here? It used to work the first couple times after I reboot my computer.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?